# How to make BufferedRead() class read in folder?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read and display the content of a group of txt files in specific folder with Java. I'm getting error in line with BufferedRead class. What I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryShow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f = new File("D:\\Files"); // current directory

        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("D:\\Files");
             String line = null;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
             }
            System.out.print("     file:");
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The more I make this comment, the less I understand why people would NOT paste the error they get when asking a question. What are you afraid of ? Are you actually ashamed of having an error, so you don't want the world to see it ? Do you think saying "error" will auto-magically allow people to know exactly what happens ? Source code is harder to read than error messages. They are **absolutely** vital to troubleshoot problems, so please, even though the problem here is simple to solve, in the future, please, do post error messages along with the offending code.

Comment: Sorry. Error: The constructor BufferedReader(String) is undefined at DirectoryShow.main

Comment: Thanks. Please note that the rather rash tone of my previous comment is not meant to be taken personally, but is the result of seeing countless questions suffering from the same issue. Just hope some people will understand the problem by reading this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors:

The first is that where you wrote

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("D:\\Files");
```

that doesn't specify a single file; you probably mean

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

The second error is that it might not the case that every file in the folder is a file, is accessible for reading, etc. In a well-designed application you should check for those things.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DirectoryShow {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("D:\\Files"); // current directory

    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputstreamReader(new FileInpupStream(file)));
         String line = null;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
         }
        br.close();
        System.out.print("     file:");
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
    }

}
```

}